# React: When rendered API JSON, fetch again content from a url string

Tags: reactjs, fetch

Title may be misleading.

Basically, I have a JSON document. And one string has a URL. In that URL there's more strings. So the plan is to render that too.

JSON 1 (https://example.com/api/):

```
"results": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Test 1",
      "url": "https://example.com/api/user",
     }
]
```

Json in "url" from JSON 1 (https://example.com/api/user):

```
"websites": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "owner": "David"
         }
    ]
```

So the problem is I can render everything from the first fetch. But I need to render the "**owner**" from the second JSON.

And here is how I have the component built:

```
export class CharacterList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            users: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://example.com/api/')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => {
                this.setState({
                    users: json
                })
            });
    }
```

And the rendering. Where it says **OWNER="DAVID"**, I need to render the content from the "owner" string in the second JSON, fetched from the first json data ("url"). I can't try to figure it out. I can render **user.name** with no problem.

```
render() {
        const { users } = this.state;
            return(
                <React.Fragment>
                <ul>
                    {users.results.map(user => (
                        <li key={user.id}>
                            <p>{user.name}</p>
                            <p>{OWNER="DAVID"}</p>
                        </li>
                        ))}
                </ul>
                </React.Fragment>
                );
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's a bit complicated since there are two different APIs and also if you'd really like to display each owner's name then that costs a lot of fetching along with longish response times. I'd suggest, if possible, to think about rearranging the two JSON structures somehow.

Nevertheless, here is a seemingly appropriate solution to your issue:

```
...
fetchUserData = async (url) => {
   const userData = await fetch(url);
   return userData;
}

// render
...
<ul>
   {users.results.map(async user => {
      const userData = await this.fetchUserData(user.url);
      return (
         <li key={user.id}>
            <p>{user.name}</p>
            <p>{userData[0].owner}</p>
         </li>
      );
   })}
</ul>
```

If each user could have more than one websites, as *websites* is an array, then you should iterate this as well. The solution above shows only the first owner's name of the current user.